# SDR - Manual FFT PSD vs pylab PSD

Tags: fft, power-spectral-density, software-defined-radio, numpy

I am trying to calculate the power spectral density step by step using numpy FFT and comparing it to the PSD calculated by pylab PSD. Difference b/w plots of both methods can be visualized from in figures below.

```
#*************************PSD using pylab PSD**************************
import math
from rtlsdr import RtlSdr
import pylab as mpl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sdr = RtlSdr()
sdr.rs = 2.4e6
sdr.fc = 935e6
sdr.gain = 40
samplest = ()
psd_scant = ()
psd_logt = ()
samples = sdr.read_samples(256*1024)
psd_scan, f=mpl.psd(samples, NFFT=1024, Fc=sdr.fc/1e6, Fs=sdr.rs/1e6)
psd_log = 10*np.log10(psd_scan)

#*************************Step by Step PSD using FFT**************************
n=256
x= np.array_split(samples, n)

xdf = pd.DataFrame(x)
xdft =xdf.transpose()
NFFT = 1024
xfft = np.fft.fft(xdft, n=1024, axis=0)[:1024, :]
xfftt=xfft.transpose()

PSD = np.abs(xfftt)**2
PSD_log = 10*np.log10(PSD)
PSD_shifted = np.fft.fftshift(PSD_log)

Final = PSD_shifted.mean(axis=0)

plt.xlabel('Frequency'); plt.ylabel('PSD')
plt.grid('on')
plt.plot(f,Final)
```

[PSD Calculated using FFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEMdK.png)
**Hints/ Help required **

1. *To compute the manual PSD plot same as pylab PSD will be appreciated.*
2. *How the y axis can be corrected.*
   [image: pylab PSD]

[image: Step by step numpy fft psd]

Comment: Can’t see the figures, take the links out of the code portion, thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the pylab PSD implementation? If they do some frequency averaging (Welch method for example) then just doing the magnitude square of the fft would not give you the same result… otherwise I’d look at scaling factor issues (google “PSD scaling”)

Comment: Like I thought, you're comparing apples to oranges. Please review [pylab PSD](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.psd.html), update your method, and get back to us!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.